# Copy/paste cells based on header value

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a macro that would allow me to update a table with data from another table. 
The only thing is that the two tables don't have the same headers and I would like to copy and paste cells only based on the "header value".

The two differents tables are not in the same worksheet.

If that can help:

Input

[image]

Output

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Create a `nested loop`, First loop: Loop through the output table headers, Second loop: Loop Through the input headers, third: IF loop1 value "x" = loop2 value "y" then copy data ... ect ect.

Comment: The way I usually do something like this is, I use a function that finds and returns the header, either as range or only the column (as Long), and then I use this function to address the cells.

Comment: Also, how about a pivot table? Seems like you just wanna see a few things, from alot of things. Sounds like job for Mr. PivotTable.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions! I'll try them and will keep you in touch.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to use ADODB.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim sql As String
    Dim vFild()
    Dim rngFild As Range, rng As Range
    Dim strFild As String
    Dim n As Integer

    Set Ws = Sheets("Output")
    With Ws
        Set rngFild = .Range("a1", .Range("a1").End(xlToRight))
    End With
    For Each rng In rngFild
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve vFild(1 To n)
        vFild(n) = "[" & rng & "]"
    Next rng

    strFild = Join(vFild, ",")

    sql = "select " & strFild & "from [Input$] "

    exeSQL Ws, sql

End Sub


Sub exeSQL(Ws As Worksheet, strSQL As String)

    Dim Rs As Object
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim i As Integer

    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"


    Set Rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Rs.Open strSQL, strConn

    If Not Rs.EOF Then
         With Ws
            .Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1).ClearContents
            'For i = 0 To Rs.Fields.Count - 1
            '   .Cells(1, i + 1).Value = Rs.Fields(i).Name
            'Next
            .Range("a" & 2).CopyFromRecordset Rs
        End With
    End If
    Rs.Close
    Set Rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it and will keep you in touch